# How do I get the data model in ios 9?

Tags: ios, swift, model, bundle

I'm trying to run this project in ios 9.3 on an iphone 4s. It's a snapchat clone on github.

https://github.com/Kesoyuh/simple-snapchat

This code gives me an error in ios 9.3, but works on the simulator (ios 10).

```
func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        var context: NSManagedObjectContext?

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        } else {
            // iOS 9.0 and below - however you were previously handling it
            guard let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Model", withExtension:"momd") else {
                fatalError("Error loading model from bundle")
            }
            guard let mom = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL) else {
                fatalError("Error initializing mom from: \(modelURL)")
            }
            let psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: mom)
            context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
            let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
            let docURL = urls[urls.endIndex-1]
            let storeURL = docURL.appendingPathComponent("Model.sqlite")
            do {
                try psc.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: storeURL, options: nil)
            } catch {
                fatalError("Error migrating store: \(error)")
            }

        }
        return context!
    }
```

The problem is where it says "iOS 9.0 and below" where it says Bundle.main.url it's returning that error there:  "Error loading model from bundle".  I have never messed with any of this model / bundle stuff and was wondering if anyone could help with this?  I really want it to work on my iphone so i can see/use the camera part because that doesn't work on the simulator. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your code on iPhone 4s then you need to set iOS deployment target accordingly that are supported by iPhone 4s, Currently you set iOS deployment target 9.3 that are not supported by iPhone 4s. Set your Project iOS Deployment target as 8.0,

Steps:- Click on Project -> Info -> iOS Deployment target.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: my 4s has 9.3 though